# Reload UITableView when navigating back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigation

I have a top level `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView`.  The top level `UIViewController` instantiates a `NavigationController`, and pushes another `UIViewController` onto the `NavigationController`.  I.E. we push into a new, second view.  This second view has the usual "Back" button in the upper left hand corner to allow you to navigate back to the top level view.

Is it possible, when navigating back to the top level view from the second view, to redraw the `UITableView` in the top level view, using data generated in the second view, by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the top level and if so, how does one do this?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

All you need to do is this (in your UIViewController that has a UITableView). You don't have to worry about what happens at cell-level at this point.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // to reload selected cell
}
```

Just add the code above to your controller, and you'll see that the right thing happens when you come back from your second view. The call to `reloadData` tells the table view that it needs to refresh its cells from your model, and everything else follows nicely.

Comment: i used this method, but had to move the code from my didViewLoad to viewWillAppear as they where both firing on initial load. For me it was a bigger problem because i need to download the new item details from a web service

Answer (score 14):

If you only want to reload the cell that was selected, override `viewWillAppear:` in your custom subclass of `UITableViewController` like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; // clears selection
    if (selectedRowIndexPath) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

NOTE: Assuming you've left `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` set to `YES` (the default), you must get the index path of the selected row before calling `super`, which clears the selection.

Also, the [solution of @ZoranSimic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747988/242933) to just call `[self.tablView reloadData]` is acceptable as it's less code and still efficient.

Finally, perhaps the best way to keep your table view's cells in sync with the model objects they represent is to do like `NSFetchedResultsController` and use key-value observing (KVO) and/or `NSNotification` to inform your table view controller when model objects have changed so that it can reload the corresponding cells. The table view controller could begin observing changes to its model objects in `viewDidLoad` and end observing in `dealloc` (and anywhere you [manually unload `self.view`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541216/what-is-the-proper-way-to-unload-views-in-ios-6-in-a-memory-warning-apple-doc-f)).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the [answer of Zoran Simic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747988/1864294) here the Swift code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Be careful not to get data from `viewDidLoad()` when you want to reload data from `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: *"Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes."*

Answer (score 5):

You could implement the methods of `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and create the logic for the refreshing when popping view controllers.

Another way to do this would be implementing on your table view controller some logic on `viewWillAppear`, to refresh based on the data of the popped view controller.

If you need to send data from the second view controller to the first view controller, remember that your second view controller "doesn't" know the existence of the previous view controller. It should be transparent for it. You should implement some protocol to make the second view controller send data to the first view controller. It would be a third option to this problem, since your first view controller would be the delegate and the second view controller would be sending info to the delegate, you could be preparing your table view (first view controller) to reload, based on the received data.

Answer (score 3):

`viewWillAppear` gets called every time the view appears include the first time.
Here is my solution for reload the view only when you navigate back

I create one variable in `.h file` of my `ViewController` for checking that it is the first time I go to this `ViewController` or when I navigate back

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isViewExist;
```

After that in `viewWillAppear`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(!self.isViewExist){
        self.isViewExist = YES; // check it is the first time you go to this ViewController -> don't reload anything
    }else{
        [self.tableView reloadData]; // to reload the tableview data
        // or your can refresh anything in your ViewController as you want
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can help now.

For **Swift 2+**

In your viewDidAppear method:

If you want to reload all table:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

If you want to reload only the cell selected.

```
let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
if (index != nil){
  self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([index], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 3

```
let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if (index != nil){
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [index!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
```